# ElasticSearch 5 for content searching settings and query with ngram

Tags: elasticsearch, n-gram, elasticsearch-5

this is my ES5 index settings :

```
dev: {
  settings: {
    index: {
      number_of_shards: "5",
      provided_name: "dev",
      creation_date: "1491735064046",
      analysis: {
        filter: {
          trigrams_filter: {
            type: "ngram",
            min_gram: "3",
            max_gram: "3"
            }
         },
        analyzer: {
          trigrams: {
            filter: [
              "lowercase",
              "trigrams_filter"
            ],
            type: "custom",
            tokenizer: "standard"
           }
         }
       },
     number_of_replicas: "1",
     uuid: "2dcgz81ET0GRFa-EEwsUhA",
     version: {
       created: "5020299"
     }
   }
 }
```

},

this query would give 1 result as expected:

```
{'from': 0,
 'query': {'bool': {'filter': [{'term': {'public': True}}],
                    'must': [{'multi_match': {'fields': ['author_name',
                                                         'title^5',
                                                         'title_ngram',
                                                         'title.ngram',
                                                         'title.stemmed',
                                                         'text^3',
                                                         'text.stemmed',
                                                         'keywords',
                                                         'keywords.stemmed',
                                                         'categories',
                                                                 'categories.stemmed'],
                                              'fuzziness': 'AUTO',
                                              'query': u'austrailia'}}]}},
 'size': 20}
```

because there is a article with title `australia`.

however this query for `aust` would not give any result:

```
{'from': 0,
 'query': {'bool': {'filter': [{'term': {'public': True}}],
                    'must': [{'multi_match': {'fields': ['author_name',
                                                         'title^5',
                                                         'title_ngram',
                                                         'title.ngram',
                                                         'title.stemmed',
                                                         'text^3',
                                                         'text.stemmed',
                                                         'keywords',
                                                         'keywords.stemmed',
                                                         'categories',
                                                             'categories.stemmed'],
                                              'fuzziness': 'AUTO',
                                              'query': u'austrailia'}}]}},
 'size': 20}
```

I've read through all the ES5 documentation but still can't get this to work.

Comment: Can you also provide the mapping for all those fields in your queries and some sample documents?

Comment: You will not get something for `aust` because your ngrams are for only 3 letters: `"min_gram": "3",          "max_gram": "3"` and `aust` is made of 4 letters. If you want `aust` or anything longer than that to match then use `max_gram: 10` or something bigger.

Answer (score 1):

You will not get something for `aust` because your `ngrams` are for only 3 letters: `"min_gram": "3", "max_gram": "3"` and `aust` is made of 4 letters. If you want `aust` or anything longer than that to match then use `max_gram: 10` or something bigger.

Comment: i changed max_grams: 10 still no results

Comment: Then share the complete mapping (including the one for `title` field), the complete query and the document you think your query needs to match.